# Jquery methods are not getting loaded form .js file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 and ruby 2.0

1. I have included select2 jquery plugin in my app.
2. I have included below jquery methods in a js file to apply select2 plugin feature to select box

   ```
    $('#order_location_id').select2();
   ```
3. This is the select box to which am assigning the select2 feature.

   ```
    <%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :name, prompt: true, :required => true,  :class => 'chosen-select' %>
   ```

The problem am facing is:
If i user $(document).ready(); : The jquery method is getting applied to the select box only when the entire page is refreshed and it is not applied when back button is clicked or when i reach the page by clicking the link of that page.

so i used $(document).(page:load, function(){..}); : here the problem am facing is, the jquery method is not applied to the select box when the page is refreshed but it is getting applied when i navigate from other pages.

This problem is not only for select2 plugin. It is the same for all other jquery methods, there is some problem in loading of jquery methods.
I dono what to use other than $(document).ready(); and $(document).on(page:load, function{..});

Could any one help me in this.

Comment: check what your <select> code is render on both occassion

Comment: in both occassions my select code is the same with the same id

Comment: check your console see if any error is coming

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery live event [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and if you are using latest vesion of jquery then syntax is changed instead of using .live we use .on..more details are in link

Comment: I think you are telling about using like this: $(document).on(page:load, function{..});

Comment: yeah and don't use page:load event instead of that use click or some other events, btw .on anyways doesn't support page:load event. Events are mentioned in the link. First read it thoroughly and then proceed further :)

Comment: you dint understand my question right.. am not going to do any click events.. my jquery methods should get loaded as soon as i came to that page.